# Proxy request URL had no scheme

Tags: python, proxy

I am running a python script in a docker-container which first fetches a few proxies, and then passes uses these proxies for some get-requests.

My code looks like this:

```
instances = mngr.getRunningProxiesIP()
print("####")
print(instances)
print("####")
proxy = instances[1][0] 
proxy+=":3128"
print(proxy)
print(type(proxy))

response = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json",proxies={"https":proxy, "http":proxy})
```

When executing this, I first get this output:

```
sv_proxies  | ####
sv_proxies  | [['54.93.232.96'], ['3.124.2.94'], ['18.156.122.36']]
sv_proxies  | ####
sv_proxies  | 3.124.2.94:3128  <--- this is the actual prox I try to use
sv_proxies  | <class 'str'>
```

But when the `requests.get` is being executed, I always get the following error:

```
sv_proxies  | requests.exceptions.InvalidURL: Proxy URL had no scheme, should start with http:// or https://
```

I tried prefixing `https` or `http`but it didn't work.

So the weird thing is: When I take this proxy: `3.124.2.94:3128` and put it in another script, which does not dynamically fetch the proxies, it works just fine..

This script looks like this:

```
import requests
import time
prxy = "3.124.2.94:3128"
proxies = {
    "https":prxy,
    "http":prxy
}
while True:
    result = requests.get("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json",proxies=proxies)
    print(result.json())
```

As you can see, I also didn't add `http` or `https` before the IP..

Has anyone an idea on what could cause this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can proxies have ports?

Comment: I have multiple EC2 instances which are running squid on port 3128, so yes :D